# suggestedFilename - gives me back gibberish

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I'm having a problem using `suggestedFilename` with Hebrew file names.
I'm sending a response like this:

```
_fileName = [response suggestedFilename];
```

but for example if the `NSURLResponse` is something like this:

```
        <NSHTTPURLResponse: ........> { URL: https://SOMETHINGSOMETHINGSOMETHING/A%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA.txt } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
        "Accept-Ranges" =     (
            bytes
        );
        Connection =     (
            "Keep-Alive"
        );
        "Content-Disposition" =     (
            "Attachment; filename=\"A\U00d7\U0091\U00d7\U0093\U00d7\U0099\U00d7\U00a7\U00d7\U0094 \U00d7\U00a2\U00d7\U009d \U00d7\U0090\U00d7\U0095\U00d7\U00aa.txt\""
        );
        "Content-Length" =     (
            0
        );
        "Content-Type" =     (
            "text/plain"
        );
        Date =     (
            "Sun, 04 Mar 2018 15:20:41 GMT"
        );
        Etag =     (
            "SOMETHING"
        );
        "Keep-Alive" =     (
            "timeout=2, max=100"
        );
        "Last-Modified" =     (
            "Wed, 28 Feb 2018 12:46:52 GMT"
        );
        Server =     (
            SOMETHING
        );
        Vary =     (
            "User-Agent"
        );
        "X-Frame-Options" =     (
            SAMEORIGIN
        );
    }   
}
```

I'm getting in _filename : `A××××§× ×¢× ×××ª.txt`

instead of : `Aבדיקה עם אות.txt`

any ideas?

Comment: What's the text encoding on the filename in the attachment? Looks like it might need to be reinterpreted in a different encoding.

Comment: The file is not an attachment, the url is a url to the file, can I reinterpret the file name after I get it?